# loop to get the href attr and put as a variable as text in html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting myself confused with the DOM.

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="my-list">
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="title"><a href="some_url"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="my-list">
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="title"><a href="some_url"></a></div>
</div>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
var myList = $(".my-list");
for (var i=0;  i < myList.length; i++) {

    // what I want is at myList[i] to get the
    // $(".title a").attr("href") as a variable
    // and then put this variable as text
    // into the html of the $(".name") html

}
```

What is a good way to construct this?

Comment: `$(".my-list > a")` should retrieve just the `<a>` tags that are children/descendants of your `my-list` classed elements. That'd simplify the looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".my-list").each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var href = element.find('.title a').attr('href');
    element.find('.name').text(href);
});
```

Comment: Eli that's amazing! Learned something new again :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$('.my-list').each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    $('.name',self).html( $('.title a', self).attr('href') );
});
```

Here's an [example of it working](http://jsfiddle.net/Ilmv/73xwz/)

Comment: Just a comment, it is recommended to use .`find` instead of specifying a context, because it internally just uses `.find` and has better performance.

Comment: No criticism, just wanted to share that with you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not much for jquery but this a sure way to do it

```
$(".my-list").each(function(item){
    var divs = item.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(var i in divs){
        if(typeof divs[i] != 'undefined' && divs[i].className == 'name'){
        divs[i].innerHTML = item.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Johan! I am going to study your suggestion as well! Thank you!